# AdView and search view not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, ads, searchview

Hi now My app doesn't show ads and search view it used to show before but I created navigation menu and it doesn't show them anymore. Here is my code. I couldn't paste it here because stack overflow doesn't let me

`MainActivity.java`
https://pastebin.com/zVQCQRAc

`ActivityMain.xml`
https://pastebin.com/UUbStvE0

`Appbar_main.xml`
https://pastebin.com/4tR6B0Hm

`Content_main.xml`
https://pastebin.com/ipxy3gSU

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ededed"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also it would be a huge help if anyone could tell me how can show search in menu bar.
Thanks.

Comment: " if anyone could tell me how can show search in menu bar" - please consider a new question for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to add `SearchView`  in `Menu`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search_album"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/str_search_album"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />

</menu>
```

than create a Searchable.xml in **`res-XMl`** folder like this

[image]

**Searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_trips"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Than add this in your manifest file

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

add this code in Your Activity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_album_search, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search_album);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;

    }
```

For more Information **[How to Create a Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)**

Comment: can you explain more @Johndoe

Comment: @Johndoe by using above code your search menu will display in action bar

Comment: I mean the main activity is not showing admob banner ads everything else is ok in the code

Comment: @Johndoe than what about this **if anyone could tell me how can show search in menu bar**

Comment: and what should I write in java

Comment: yeah problem with search is solved but ads in recycler view are still not showing

Comment: @Johndoe happy to help you

Comment: @Johndoe you need to ask a new question for  ads in recycler view

Comment: can u help with that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427673/admob-ads-not-showing-in-android-recycler-view