# Admob ads not showing in Android recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, ads, adbannerview

Hi there my app is not showing ads in Android recycler view I want to show the ads at the bottom of my app but it is not displaying them I don't want to show native ads I only want to show a single banner at the bottom. It is a dictionary app which uses Sqlite database to load data native ads will not suit it. Can u please help here is my code.
Main activity.java

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (mAdView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And here is my content main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you check logcat for error code

Comment: @ not yet but it is loading the ad and not showing it in the recycler view

Comment: **ad and not showing it in the recycler view** means..? @

Comment: @prem It has something to do with the layout

Comment: you want to shaow add below recyclerview or in the recyclerviie @J

Comment: @prem below the recylerview at the bottom

Comment: your layout is create try to add test ads

Comment: @prem yes I'm trying to show test ads but I will change the adunit later because the app is still in development

Comment: its ok you can show test add during development

Comment: @prem did u find the problem

Comment: your layout is correct my friend i suggest you to try test add

Comment: read this https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: @prem I'm using navigation drawer could that cause problem

Comment: i think not @John

Comment: @prem ok I will try it and get back to you. thanks

Comment: sure letme know if u have any query

Comment: please remove code of layout_below from recyclerview, it think it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add on OnCreate**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"Your ad unit id from admob");
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("Add Your Device id").build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Override Methods**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
         mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
         mAdView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
         mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Your XML File**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer" />
```

Comment: Write it below oncreate

Comment: @prem worked fine with my own java code all I did was change the xml to your xml